# how can I install some program in silent mode?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, installation

I am developing a program in C# .NET 4, my program is kind of a installer that installs some  applications and services such as windows media player 11 and adobe flash player and so on.

I need to make these installations run in silent mode and users would just see my installation form.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you seen http://ninite.com? Your phrasing screams "I'm writing a trojan", for what that's worth.

Comment: Trojan with an installer.  LOL :)

Comment: think adware. how many legitimate apps have you installed that also come with some unwanted extras, unbeknownst to you?

Comment: Can you let us know more about your company so we can all avoid it like the plague?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items you need to deploy come in MSI format, you can always use a toolkit like [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) to build your installer and install the other MSIs silently using [msiexec.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314881) with the /qn command line switch. (Or use the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) from your application to invoke msiexec.exe /qn on whatever you want to install).

If they don't have an MSI to install with, there are a couple things you can do.  Many installers have a command line switch that let's them install silently.  If there is no way to install silently, you can use a tool like [AdminStudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/adminstudio.htm).  These tools have functionality that will scan your computer before and after you run an installation and help you create a redistributable package of your own.  You can then make add them to your main package in silent mode.